# advice about hosting site choose for android application and mysql database

Tags: java, android, mysql, hosting

I'm continuing with the Java programming of an Android app. Currently I use a local mysql server controlled with phpmyadmin. Having arrived at a good point, I was starting to look for a good hosting site. However, on the internet they speak mostly of the best for some services like wordpress. For this reason, do you have any advice on mysql and Android databases? I was inclined to start with one for free (I found 000webhost for example) but on the internet those that are free are not recommended. At a low price there are several such as hostinger, keliweb and many others. Should I start directly with a paid one? Thank you so much for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a good move to make. I have used iPage for about 5 years now and I've never had any issue with them. I also offer hosting with unlimited mysql database, domain, emails and bandwidth as a re-seller agent for iPage at $75/year with no hidden charges. [I'm on Twitter](https://twitter.com/cazewonder)

Answer (score 0):

Well if your project is not large scale then it'll be good to go with 000webhost, it offers quiet nice service for free.
Only problem with 000webhost is that you need to use filezilla for better files uploading.

And if you are really looking for paid hosting then go for 1&1 IONOS.
They'll only charge 12$ for first year which will give you a good idea whether you really need a paid hosting or not.